# How to make ncurses display special characters similarly to how cout does it

Tags: c++, ncurses

I've been writing a program in c++ and decided that using curses would be a better way to do things (to make things cross-platform).  It mostly works fine, but there's one problem.  In my original code, whenever I wrote `std::cout << char(30)` it would output `▲`.  I used this in parts of my program.  Now, when I use `addch(char(30))`, it writes `^[something I don't know because it's overwritten by something else]`.

I've been searching for a long time on how to fix this problem.  People say some special characters that curses includes, but none of them are what I want.  People say that I should try to use `-lncursesw`, but my compiler can't find it.  I know that this is a unicode character, but how come I was able to use it before?

I'm on Windows using mingw64 to compile my code.  I'm fine with many different ways of fixing it, as long as it's cross-platform.  I could try to find some way of making unicode work (but the fact that I can't use `-lncursesw` seems to say I can't).  I'm okay with including a character table, but I don't know how to do this or how to make curses use it.  In the end, I'm just wanting to know: How can I use these special characters that I can normally use with `cout`?

Comment: I put good odds on `ncurses` doing its duty by emitting an escape sequence to ensure what you asked it to do actually happens -- but unfortunately, you aren't using the display method it's expecting to write to, and the one you're actually using doesn't understand the sequence.

Comment: P.S. I don't think `std::cout << char(30)` counts as cross-platform. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The wide-character calls supported by [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) include [`wadd_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wch.3x.html) and [`waddwstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html), which generally support UTF-8 encoding.  If you're using the "ncurses" library, it's likely that there is an "ncursesw" for the same platform (even mingw, though [this page](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/NCurses/) seems to have overlooked building/providing that: the instructions omit the `--enable-widec` option for instance).

The [`addch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) function accepts only an 8-bit character value.  Your parameter does not fit into an 8-bit value.  ncurses (unlike X/Open) allows a *sequence* of 8-bit values to be passed to `addch` and interpreted as a multibyte character (such as UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

You’re depending on a particular code page or character set.  The portable way to fix this is to use wide characters and the Unicode equivalent.  Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
  constexpr wchar_t uptriangle = L'\u25B2';

  std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
  std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
  std::wcout << uptriangle << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

You would either need to use the wide-character version of ncurses or output `u8"\u2582"` in a version that supports UTF-8, such as Windows with code page 65001 or Unix with a UTF8 locale.

Comment: The problem with this is that the windows command line doesn't work well (and doesn't work at all by default) with unicode.  Also, ncurses doesn't even accept `wchar_t`s as an acceptable form of output.

Comment: To me personally, I feel like the best thing to do would be to somehow make the program use a particular code page, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @sudgy The version of ncurses that supports wide characters is ncursesw (and the interface is standardized as an extension to X/Open Curses). Modern versions of Windows and MSVC should support `std::wcout`.

Comment: See here for instructions on how to change the Windows code page to UTF-8.  I do not recommend using any other code page in new programs.  https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

Comment: I don't want to have to change the registry to make the code work, I want the code to be completely self-containing.  I know that the terminal accepts these characters.  Code page 437 has everything I need, I would think some combination of setlocale() and some ncurses function should be all I need.  Is there really no way to make the code compatible for different systems without any changes to the system itself?

Comment: You *can* set the currently-active code page to 437, on Windows, but this is no easier than setting it to UTF-8, less portable, and less useful. So I don’t recommend it.

Comment: Also, on any system whatsoever, you need to set your locale for anything to work.  If you try to use CP437, you need the same code to set that code page as you would for CP65001. Therefore, neither is more “self-contained” than the other.